# ExtJS. Can not buld calendar app with ExtJS 6 GPL

Tags: extjs

On sencha app build raises with

> com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency :
>   Ext.calendar.store.Calendars

JS code

```
Ext.define('keybook.store.Remote', {
    extend: 'Ext.calendar.store.Calendars',
    alias: 'store.calendar-remote',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/Calendars'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendar is a part of Ext JS Enterprise.